# Нужно понять как работает DataTable

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('sdfsdsdf');
    $('#dt-basic').DataTable( {
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        lengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50],
        searching: false,
        ordering: false,

        columns: [
            { name: "name", width: "20%", className: "table-text-align-center" },
            { name: "address", width: "20%", className: "table-text-align-center" },
            { name: "status", width: "5%", className: "table-text-align-center" },
            { name: "paymentStatus", width: "5%", className: "table-text-align-center" },
            { name: "startAt", width: "15%", className: "table-text-align-center" },
            { name: "endAt", width: "15%", className: "table-text-align-center" },
            { name: "days", width: "5%", className: "table-text-align-center" },
            { name: "actions", width: "5%", className: "table-text-align-center" },
        ],
        ajax: {
            url:'/account/api/objects',
            type: "GET",
            headers: authHeaders
        },
    } );
});
```

PHP обработка:

```
public function getApi(Request $request)
    {
        $authorization = explode(' ', $request->headers->get('authorization'))[1];

        $objects = SportObject::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($authorization){
            return $query->where('api_token', $authorization);
        })->offset($request->get('start'))->limit($request->get('length'))->get();

        //dd($request->all());
        $data = [];
        foreach ($objects as $object) {

            $data[] = [
                $object->name,
                $object->getAddress(),
                $object->getStatus(),
                $object->getPaymentStatus(),
                Carbon::parse($object->start_at)->format('d-m-Y H:s'),
                Carbon::parse($object->end_at)->format('d-m-Y H:s'),
                $object->pastDuePaymentDays(),
                '<a href="#" class="badge badge-success" title="Редагувати"><i class="fal fa-edit"></i></a>'
            ];
        }
        return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
    }
```

Мне нужно понять:
 1. Как сделать нормальную надпись слева?
 2. Как сделать нормальную пагинацию, чтобы отображало количество страниц, не больше чем может быть. + не работают клавиши пагинации вперед и назад

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного разабрался 
Теперь фраза Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries (filtered from 23 total entries)
Но страниц в пагинации только 1...  Почему?
Изменил параметры, которые возвращаю 
return response()->json(['data' => $data,'recordsTotal' => $sportObjectsTotal, 'draw' => $request->get('draw'),  'recordsFiltered' => $objects->count()]);

Answer (score 0):

вот какие данные нужно передавать:

```
return response()->json(['data' => $data,'recordsTotal' => $sportObjectsTotal,   'recordsFiltered' => $sportObjectsTotal]);
```

recordsTotal и recordsFiltered - одно число